# How to have the Rigid Body Constraint of an Animation Nodes's Empty point to other instances instead of the original objects?

Tags: animation-nodes, rigid-body-simulation

I know the question might be a bit convoluted, so I'll try to explain here what I'm doing.

I'm using Blender 2.93.5 and Animation Nodes 2.3.0.

I want to realize, in 3D, an equalizer-style audio visualization, where each frequency bar tip has a smaller item bouncing on top; something like this:

[image: eq-example]

I have the working version without bouncing tips...

[image: v1]

...and I have a working example for the moving tip, constrained using an `Empty` with `Rigid Body Constraint` physics enabled on "Generic", with only the Z Axis free to move:

[image: original objs]

Now the problem is that when instantiating all the eq bars, every `Empty` instance continue to point to the original "center" and "tip" objects, resulting in a mess bouncing all around:

[image: mess]

I can manually make every `Empty` instance point to the correct instantiated obj, instead of the original one...

[image: man-edit]

...here i.e. the `Empty.011` is highlighted and I edited `Cube.Tip` to be `Cube.Tip.011`.

Unfortunately this solution is not *stable*, because as soon as I move something and the animation nodes editor updates, the manual edit is being overwritten (i.e. if I increase the number of eq bars).

Is there a solution to this?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with "bouncing on top"....so it should not just show the maximum value, but "dance" somehow? have you maybe an example yt link how it should look like?

Comment: but for your "problem"...i don't think that this is possible right now with animation nodes....except....you use the script node and then you can do it yourself via python.

Comment: @Chris by "bouncing" I mean that the tips are projected on top of the bars by their up-down movement along the music and fall down due to gravity. It's a quite interesting look, it reminds me of some old Technics HiFi I had many years ago.
Thanks I'll take a look at the script node.

Comment: The other possibility is you „fake“ the falling down by some math and/or falloff. Then you could avoid scripting